# "Чушь гороховая"

Tags: фразеология

Хотелось бы узнать происхождение выражения "чушь гороховая".
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю, чем это вызвано, но отношение к гороху всегда было несколшько своеобразным, он символизировал что-то не очень настоящее, неполноценное. Cравните: при царе Горохе, шут гороховый и т.д.

Проверялась версия, что "чушь гороховая" это реальная еда, но подтверждения не нашла.